# by passing id how to get values based on the id in ajax for php program

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to get the form based on the id, so i am trying to post id using ajax but it doesn't give any response. I need help. Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#getcat').click(function () {
    jQuery('#getcat').hide();
    var divval = jQuery("select[id^='cat']").val();
    jQuery("#Loading").fadeIn();
    datastring = jQuery('#mainform').serialize();
    //datastring='id="'+divval+'"';

    jQuery.post(window.location.pathname + "?form=1", datastring, function (response) {
        jQuery("#Loading").fadeOut('fast');
        jQuery('.form_open').load();
        jQuery('.form_open').html(response);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: datastring='id="'+divval+'"';

Comment: check your browser console... is there any error